# Why do we wrap Angular app inside a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning Angular and in all the resources I've used so far I saw this in the `app.js` file:

```
(function () {

       \\\myAngularModules      

})();
```

The most commonl explainantion is an unhelpful "it's just good practice".

**Questions:**

1. Is wrapping our Angular JS code in a function really good practice? Why?
2. What sort of function is it and what does it *do*?

Please give examples where possible.

Comment: It's because, your variable wouldn't get conflict with global variable if used third party services, etc...

Comment: Look explanation here http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: Why downvoting without explaning? Downvoters please [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes).

Comment: @AlexanderKobelev that's an excellent article, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what is known as an immediately invoked anonymous function (IIFE). It allows us to create a new function scope and immediately run the code so that no variable or other items we create "leak" out and manipulate the global scope.

Leaking of your code into the global can impact other modules or 3rd party code. This also helps protect your code by making you think about what objects you are using that are not declared in your local scope.

http://gregfranko.com/blog/i-love-my-iife/ as a more detailed explanation that covers the general idea other esoteric things like minification benefits.

Answer (score 2):

> Is wrapping our Angular JS code in a function really good practice?
>   Why?

This is good practice and is called module pattern. As a pattern has it advantages and it disadvantages. However, it is one of the most used patterns in the JS world. In a few words, it allows you to declare as you want your variables, your functions etc. without having any conflict with any js code you use in your app.

For further information on the above, please have a look [here](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript).

> What sort of function is it and what does it do?

It is a classic function. Nothing more nothing less. Using the invoking operator `()` at the end, we call the function, to be executed. The latter is also known as `IIFE`, immediately invoked anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't accept your answer simply because I like your link a bit less ;)